# I am trying to install the react cogo toast on vite but I can't install it. I get some error when I install using npm package

Tags: toast

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: test@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from cogo-toast@4.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/cogo-toast
npm ERR!   cogo-toast@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-04T12_52_26_698Z-er
esolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local
\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-04T12_52_26_698Z-debug-0.log
```

how to solve this problem?